# Active users from other SE sites should be able to edit privileges descriptions on MSO

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, privileges, privileges-page, mso-mse-split

MSO is the master site for privileges descriptions, i.e. the pages listed on [`/privileges`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/). The text used on MSO is distributed to other sites on the network, and it's not possible to edit them individually on each site.

To edit those descriptions, a user needs to have 1000 reputation *on Meta Stack Overflow*. It's unlisted in the privileges descriptions pages, but I got it when I first had more than 1000 rep on MSO. *The system doesn't care that a user is a [trusted user](/privileges/trusted-user) on one of the "real" Q&A sites, and might actually be better suited to do this (based on own experience with the privileges) than someone who has 1000 rep on MSO*.

[Apparently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2778990#2778990), sending users to MSO to edit the descriptions is the standard response to "*Please change the privileges documentation*" topics on child meta sites. But even very high reputation users on other sites might not actually be able to do that, when they don't actively participate on MSO.

---

**This behavior makes no sense and needs to be changed.** The privileges description editing privilege should not be based on MSO reputation, but e.g. on network reputation (minus the account linking bonuses), or the highest reputation a user has on *any* SE site.

Alternatively, there should be a way for users that have 101+ MSO rep to suggest edits to the privileges descriptions. Currently, it's not possible to suggest edits on the privilege description pages with below 1000 MSO reputation. These low MSO rep users might already have all privileges somewhere else, so it doesn't make sense to not allow them to describe these privileges. The problem with this method is, of course, possibly too many bad suggestions from users having no substantial reputation anywhere.

Comment: @casperOne How so? It'd just apply to MSE rather than MSO in the future, unless the complete "propagating privileges descriptions" concept will be changed right with it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just post a meta request for the verbiage change? This text is relatively static, and shouldn't change much unless there's a feature request fulfilled.  What do you need?

Comment: @casperOne Nothing will change by creating a real "Meta Stack Overflow" in regards to this issue, except that editing descriptions will happen on MSE rather than MSO. I'll be happy to edit this post to refer to MSE instead of MSO once that change is live.

Comment: @casperOne The mechanic can be separated from the motive, here. Regardless of the motive and the future of a split, it still remains that this still *is* the central home for the engine, and the ability to suggest edits on the privilege pages is somewhat independent of the split.

Comment: Thanks for this question, I didn't know about this feature :) I was about to submit a request, actually.

Comment: @minitech Aren't you glad you barely made the cut and aren't judged solely for your 25k+ rep on SO? ;-)

Comment: Yes `;)`​​​​​​​

Comment: @minitech You're a moderator here: Does this master copy of privileges descriptions (now help center) still exist? Or can this be closed?

Comment: @DanielBeck: I don’t think it still exists, no. I might just be missing it, though.

Comment: The ability for privileges pages to be edited has long been deprecated; see [Allow users with enough reputation on Meta.SO to edit the privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209527/allow-users-with-enough-reputation-on-meta-so-to-edit-the-privileges-page)